# When is memory allocated to classes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, v8

In Javascript, memory allocation is done when values are initially declared be it a variable or a function. I'd like to know if memory is also allocated when a class is declared (either by class declaration or class expression) or is it allocated only when class instances are created ?

Answer (score 2):

Classes (not only instances, but the `class` itself) are objects. Objects (collections of key-value pairs, of which classes will have a few) require memory. So the addition of a `class` that doesn't get instantiated anywhere will theoretically increase memory usage.

That said, in essentially all cases, it'll be so low to be completely imperceptible. There are better things to worry about.

Creating a new instance from the class will create *another* object whose internal prototype points to the class prototype object, resulting in (a very tiny bit) more memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.
Memory is allocated for a class when it is defined (new) keyword. The amount of memory allocated may differ from when instances of the class are created.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is allocated when instances are created.  It would not make sense to allocate more memory than is needed to the class declaration itself before instances are being created as the engine cannot know in advance if you are going to create one or a million instances of a class.